# SCAN_SDT_UNKNOWN - Motorola OPOS Scanner

Tags: motorola, opos

I am receiving an odd error with my scanner integration. I am making use of an OPOS scanner in my program. When the program closes I disable, release and close the device, but no other application can use it after my program runs. Also if I restart no application can use it. Not even my application which causes the issue. I did find that if I do not claim the device the issue doesn't happen. I am currently trying to get a fresh copy of the DLL in case the release method is somehow corrupted? Any other ideas?

```
    public bool InitBarcode(bool overrideLGBarcode)
    {
        Util.LogMessage("Initializing barcode scanner!");
        if (_barcodeScanner == null)
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner was null. instantiating a new one");
            _barcodeScanner = new OPOSScanner();
            _barcodeScanner.AutoDisable = true;
            _barcodeScanner.DataEvent += BarcodeDataEventHandler;
            Util.LogMessage("Added event handler");
        }
        else
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner was not null");
        }

        if (_barcodeScanner.Open("STI_USBSCANNER") != 0)
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner \"STI_USBSCANNER\" could not be opened!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Util.LogMessage("STI_USBSCANNER was opened");
        }

        int result = _barcodeScanner.ClaimDevice(-1);
        Util.LogMessage("Claiming barcode scanner returned result: " + result);


        _barcodeScanner.DecodeData = true;
        _barcodeScanner.DeviceEnabled = true;
        _barcodeScanner.DataEventEnabled = true;

        return true;
    }

    public void CloseBarcode()
    {
        Util.LogMessage("Disabling, Releasing and Closing the barcode scanner!");
        _barcodeScanner.DataEvent -= BarcodeDataEventHandler;
        Util.LogMessage("Removed event handler");
        _barcodeScanner.AutoDisable = false;
        _barcodeScanner.DecodeData = false;
        _barcodeScanner.DataEventEnabled = false;
        _barcodeScanner.DeviceEnabled = false;

         if (_barcodeScanner.DeviceEnabled != false)
         {
             Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner could not be disabled!");
         }
         else
         {
             Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner was disabled!");
         }

        int result = _barcodeScanner.ReleaseDevice();
        Util.LogMessage("ReleseDevice() yielded result of: " + result);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner could not be released!");
        }
        else
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner was released!");
        }


        if (_barcodeScanner.Close() != 0)
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner could not be closed!");
        }
        else
        {
            Util.LogMessage("Barcode scanner was closed!");
        }
         _barcodeScanner = null;
    }
```

Comment: Try running it through the debug version of the OPOS Common Controls, available on the monroecs.com site.  They will log good details on state changes when the SO is opened, closed, etc.

Comment: I've seen simuler problems when opening/ claiming a device multiple times without first releasing it. It may be worth adding a Static int variable to the class and incrementing it in `InitBarcode` then deincrementing it in `CloseBarcode` to make sure your calling `CloseBarcode` the correct number of times.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for the advice. At this point we are assuming some kind of configuration issue because this on occurs on some kiosks. We haven't seen the issue on any Windows XP kiosks and only a couple Kiosks in DEV and TEST. We are continually looking into the issue. It is definitely a hair puller.

Comment: We could not figure out the issue at all. It is still happening. We have started moving away from that scanner and are starting to use Motorola's DS457 which uses Motorola's SDK and Core Scanner Driver